# Java - Using radio buttons to select an array and then an array item

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a lot of trouble searching for an answer to this problem.

I've set up a simple GUI with two columns of radio buttons, a beginning location and an ending location. Each of the below arrays lists the distance to a certain point. So the BVS array has distances to BVS, HCMS, PVS, SAU, WES, WHS, WVS.

I need to figure out how to determine mileage from the first columns radio button selection to the second columns radio button selection. If were to select PVS in the first column, and WVS in the second column, it would return 13.0.

```
double[] BVS = new double[] {0.0, 10.0, 18.0, 8.0, 4.2, 4.6, 17.0};
double[] HCMS = new double[] {10.0, 0.0, 9.6, 2.0, 5.8, 6.2, 15.0};
double[] PVS = new double[] {17.8, 9.6, 0.0, 9.8, 13.6, 14.0, 13.0};
double[] SAU = new double[] {8.0, 2.0, 9.8, 0.0, 3.8, 4.2, 17.0};
double[] WES = new double[] {4.2, 5.8, 13.6, 3.8, 0.0, 0.4, 20.8};
double[] WHS = new double[] {4.6, 6.2, 14.0, 4.2, 0.4, 0.0, 21.2};
double[] WVS = new double[] {25.0, 15.0, 13.0, 17.0, 20.8, 21.2, 0.0};

double[][] firstLocation = {BVS, HCMS, PVS, SAU, WES, WHS, WVS};
double[][] secondLocation = {BVS, HCMS, PVS, SAU, WES, WHS, WVS};
double tripMileage = 0.0
```

I need to figure out how to set tripMileage to the value determined by the two radio button selections.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't even know what these arrays represent, or why the combination of `PVS[0]` and `WVS[1]` result in 13.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare two 2d arrays; the first array is already telling you all possible distances of location 1 (first location, the first index) to location 2 (seconds location, the second index).

So, given:

```
double[] BVS  = new double[] { 0.0, 10.0, 18.0,  8.0,  4.2,  4.6, 17.0};
double[] HCMS = new double[] {10.0,  0.0,  9.6,  2.0,  5.8,  6.2, 15.0};
double[] PVS  = new double[] {17.8,  9.6,  0.0,  9.8, 13.6, 14.0, 13.0};
double[] SAU  = new double[] { 8.0,  2.0,  9.8,  0.0,  3.8,  4.2, 17.0};
double[] WES  = new double[] { 4.2,  5.8, 13.6,  3.8,  0.0,  0.4, 20.8};
double[] WHS  = new double[] { 4.6,  6.2, 14.0,  4.2,  0.4,  0.0, 21.2};
double[] WVS  = new double[] {25.0, 15.0, 13.0, 17.0, 20.8, 21.2,  0.0};
double[][] distance =        { BVS, HCMS,  PVS,  SAU,  WES,  WHS,  WVS};
```

and given you show the locations in the radioboxes with same order you used in distance array,

```
double tripMileage = distance[firstRadioIndex][secondRadioIndex];
```

Comment: Thank you, that seams to work perfectly! Now I'm just trying to figure out how to set and store variables in the GUI class, then transfer them over all at once to to the calculation class.